# Rails 4.2 : Form with multiple models - param is missing or the value

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble with Rails 4.2 to create a form with multiple models.
I'm creating a form to allow a user to order a gift card with a custom stripe payment form all in one.
I tried different ways using form_tag instead of simple_form_for and simple_fields_for and I tried all the solution provided on this website but I can't find a way out of this hell!

My form is the following :

```
     =simple_form_for @giftcard, url: gift_cards_path, html: {"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :autocomplete => "off", :enctype => "multipart/form-data", :method => "post" } do |f|

      (...)

      = field_set_tag 'Delivery mode' do
        .form-row
          = f.label :delivery_mode, 'She receive the mail'
          = f.radio_button :delivery_mode, 'email_to_recipient'
          = f.label :delivery_mode, 'I receive the mail'
          = f.radio_button :delivery_mode, 'email_to_giver'
          = f.label :delivery_mode, 'Delivery with in box with a jewel'
          = f.radio_button :delivery_mode, 'gift_box', id: 'gift_box'

      = field_set_tag 'Who is the gift for ?' do
        .form-row
          = f.input :recipient_first_name, label: 'First Name'
        .form-row
          = f.input :recipient_last_name, label: 'Last Name'
        .form-row
          = f.input :recipient_email, placeholder: 'example@mail.com', label: 'Son adresse email'
        .form-row
          = f.input :message, placeholder: 'Your message', label: 'Son message'

      = f.simple_fields_for :payment do |p|
       .form-row
         = p.input :card_number, label: 'Numéro de carte'
       .form-row
         = p.input :card_cvc, input_html: { "size" => 4, "data-stripe" => "cvv" }, label: 'CVV'
       .form-row
         = p.input :card_expiration_month, input_html: { "placeholder" => "MM", "size" => 2, "data-stripe" => "exp-month" }
         = p.input :card_expiration_year, input_html: { "placeholder" => "YYYY", "size" => 4, "data-stripe" => "exp-year" }

     .form-row
       = f.button :submit, 'Send your gift !'
```

My controller is the following :

```
def new
   @giftcard = GiftCard.new
   @payment = Payment.new
end

def create
    @giftcard = GiftCard.new(giftcard_params)
    @payment = Payment.new(creditcard_params)
    @giftcard.amount += 9.90 if @giftcard.gift_box?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @giftcard.save && @payment.process_payment
        code_coupon = CodeCoupon.create(name: giftcard.coupon, value: 0, category: 'membership', origin: 'gift')
        if giftcard.delivery_mode == 'gift_box'
          UserMailer.prepare_gift_box(@giftcard)
          UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        elsif @giftcard.delivery_mode == 'email_to_giver'
          UserMailer.send_gift_card(@giftcard, @giftcard.giver_email)
          UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        elsif @giftcard.delivery_mode == 'email_to_recipient'
          UserMailer.send_gift_card(@giftcard, @giftcard.recipient_email)
          UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @giftcard, notice: 'Votre carte cadeau à bien été créée et vous a été envoyé par email' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @giftcard }
      else
        format.html { render :new, locals: { errors: @giftcard.errors.full_messages } }
        format.json { render json: @giftcard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private

  def giftcard_params
    params.require(:gift_card).permit(:recipient_email, :recipient_first_name, :recipient_last_name, :giver_email, :giver_phone, :giver_first_name, :giver_last_name, :message, :amount, :delivery_mode, :delivery_first_name, :delivery_last_name, :delivery_street, :delivery_city, :delivery_zip)
  end

  def creditcard_params
    params.require(:payment).permit(:card_number, :card_cvc, :card_expiration_month, :card_expiration_year, :card_token )
  end
```

And the troubled model:

```
class Payment
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_cvc, :card_expiration_month, :card_expiration_year, :card_token

  validates :card_number, presence: true
  validates :card_cvc, presence: true
  validates :card_expiration_month, presence: true
  validates :card_expiration_year, presence: true

  def payment_process
    Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount: amount * 100,
      description: "paiement unique",
      source: card_token,
      currency: 'eur'
    )
  end
end
```

When I try to validate the form, it returns the following error :
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: payment:
 actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:251:in `require'
 app/controllers/gift_cards_controller.rb:56:in`creditcard_params'
 app/controllers/gift_cards_controller.rb:13:in `create'

If I remove the require in the creditcard_params method and I click on submit, I get in the log :
Unpermitted parameter: payment
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, gift_card, commit
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

**EDIT**

Here the parameters that I receive in the log :

```
    Started POST "/gift_cards" for ::1 at 2017-10-06 10:17:42 +0200
    Processing by GiftCardsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {
"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"UB1keTN7YNDhaEBdIT6cYf/qrwr/QxCpFEYwvGDBLWmYvZiVjXxFg+bQ9vaPAfQTx32d/D7jHnShsTmsqMwLrA==", 
"gift_card"=>{
  "recipient_first_name"=>"", 
  "recipient_last_name"=>"", 
  "recipient_email"=>"", 
  "message"=>"", 
  "giver_first_name"=>"", 
  "giver_last_name"=>"", 
  "giver_email"=>"", 
  "giver_phone"=>"", 
  "delivery_first_name"=>"", 
  "delivery_last_name"=>"", 
  "delivery_street"=>"", 
  "delivery_city"=>"", 
  "delivery_zip"=>"", 
  "payment"=>{
     "card_number"=>"", 
     "card_cvc"=>"", 
     "card_expiration_month"=>"", 
     "card_expiration_year"=>""
     }
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Send your gift !"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Regards

Comment: can you share the parameters which you are receiving in controller?

Comment: Hi @VaibhavDhoke thank you for you answer, I put the parameters in the EDIT part !

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, one way of achieving this will be, changes in `person_params` as below

```
def person_params
      params.require(:gift_card).permit(:recipient_email, :recipient_first_name, :recipient_last_name, :giver_email, :giver_phone, :giver_first_name, :giver_last_name, :message, :amount, :delivery_mode, :delivery_first_name, :delivery_last_name, :delivery_street, :delivery_city, :delivery_zip, payment: [:card_number, :card_cvc, :card_expiration_month, :card_expiration_year])
 end
```

This will whitelist all your parameters as you have shown in params,

Once this is done, further you will have to change your `create` action as

`@payment = Payment.new(person_params(params)[:payment])` 
instead of your code.

Addition to this there is a code change in if condition as per the model you have shown `@giftcard.save && @payment.payment_process`.

The complete solution will be as below:

```
def create
    @giftcard = GiftCard.new(giftcard_params)
    @payment = Payment.new(giftcard_params[:payment])
    @giftcard.amount += 9.90 if @giftcard.gift_box?
    respond_to do |format|
    if @giftcard.save && @payment.payment_process
        code_coupon = CodeCoupon.create(name: giftcard.coupon, value: 0, category: 'membership', origin: 'gift')
        if giftcard.delivery_mode == 'gift_box'
            UserMailer.prepare_gift_box(@giftcard)
            UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        elsif @giftcard.delivery_mode == 'email_to_giver'
            UserMailer.send_gift_card(@giftcard, @giftcard.giver_email)
            UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        elsif @giftcard.delivery_mode == 'email_to_recipient'
            UserMailer.send_gift_card(@giftcard, @giftcard.recipient_email)
            UserMailer.giftcard_recipe(@giftcard)
        end

    format.html { redirect_to @giftcard, notice: 'Votre carte cadeau à bien été créée et vous a été envoyé par email' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @giftcard }
    else
      format.html { render :new, locals: { errors: @giftcard.errors.full_messages } }
      format.json { render json: @giftcard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
    def giftcard_params
        params.require(:gift_card).permit(:recipient_email, :recipient_first_name, :recipient_last_name, :giver_email, :giver_phone, :giver_first_name, :giver_last_name, :message, :amount, :delivery_mode, :delivery_first_name, :delivery_last_name, :delivery_street, :delivery_city, :delivery_zip, payment: [:card_number, :card_cvc, :card_expiration_month, :card_expiration_year])  
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vaibhav, I actually had some other troubles with my Giftcard model and controller. So I have to fix them first and I'll give you a feedback of your solution straight after :-)